# How to write to a Kafka topic so that I get the created offset back to the writer?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I'd like to use the [Alpakka Kafka Connector](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-kafka/current/home.html) for writing to a Kafka topic, from an application made in Scala.

The return from the write seems to be `Future[Done]`. However, I think that once the write has happened (and I want to be sure it has), also the offset used in reading the topic is known. How can the writer get it?

I'd like to use the auto-generated offsets, not maintain my own. There can be many writers (that's another reason to use the autogenerated ones). The reason to want to see the offset is that then I can allow my callers to check, when they actually see that entry on the reading side.

Maybe this is not possible?

Comment: The consumers and the producers don't typically communicate. But, yes, the Producer API will return the offset metadata in the send request results

Comment: I wonder why the question was down-voted. StackOverflow recommends giving feedback in such cases.

Comment: In general, it's not possible for the reason I mentioned. Producers and consumers do not have to be online at the same time because Kafka will persist the messages in between, plus you aren't able to make up your own offset numbers anyway, and those are always auto generated... In your Future object, it should be providing a RecordMetadata object, which does contain the written offset

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is in [this snippet](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-kafka/current/producer.html#producer-as-a-flow) in the Alpakka Kafka Connector documentation.